# "Wage" vs "Wages". Another use of "wages"

Tags: articles, singular-vs-plural, countability

> Laura was complaining for a wage.
> Laura was complaining for the wage.

Which one would be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither is idiomatic. Native English speakers would not use those constructions.

Laura was complaining either because she was not being paid at all or not being paid as much as she wanted.

If the latter, she was complaining about her (low) wages.

People don't complain **for** things; they complain **about** them. That's unless you use a construction like: **He complained (about something) for valid reasons.**